# XHTTPRequests on client side

Tags: javascript, html

If I understand this right, on FireFox, since somewhere in august 2019,
XHTTPRequests can no longuer be made on client side.
Loading a local XML file made by oneself can't be loaded by xhr.
And the examples and tutorials on the web that were working before
now must be executed only on Server side?

Would there be any way to bypass this hindrance otherwise than by installing an old copy of FireFox?

I've developped a few local applications using xhr for more than a decade
to load xml files off line in order to create a readable/printable html version.
It's a bit disturbing having to revisit what was performing flawlessly for so long...

Any other suggestions (than using old versions or installing an Apache server)?

Comment: It's insecure to allow any XHR to read a user's file system. You can still read files with [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) though

Comment: I'm working offLine with a xml file produced by my own application... As for FileReader, i still found no way to assign the file directly to the reader, you have to assign it first to an INPUT element...

Comment: Yes that's true. And the browser has no idea you are working with a file you created yourself and can trust. These restrictions exists to stop malicious developers exploiting that functionality to try and steal data and so on. Unfortunately that then has an impact on the rest of us.  The best long term solution is probably to install a simple local webserver and serve your page and the XML files through that. Using an old browser just kicks the can down the road a bit